# call functions from vector of class in c++

Tags: class, c++11, vector

I am writing a program for insertion sort.I am creating a class to read print and sort a vector of integers.I have created a vector of class and I want to call functions read,sort and print from vector of class created.How to do that ?

Thanks,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class sorting
{
private:
    vector<int>arr;

public:
    void read();
    void sortt();
    void print();
};

void sorting :: read()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        arr.push_back(t);
    }

}


void sorting :: sortt()
{
    int j,temp;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        temp=arr[i];
        j=i;

        while(temp<arr[j-1] && j>0)
        {
            arr[j]=arr[j-1];
            j=j-1;

        }
        arr[j]=temp;
    }
}

void sorting :: print()
{
    for(unsigned int k=0; k<arr.size(); k++)
    {
        cout<<arr[k]<<"\t";

    }
    cout<<endl;
    arr.clear();
}


int main()
{
    vector<sorting>s;

    s.read(); // giving an error
    s.sortt(); // giving an error

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sorting s;` and not `vector<sorting>`. You defined those methods `read()` amd `sortt()` defined in the class `sorting`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I got this answer searching in google accidentally in different websites,

It is like vectors(100)

So I can call

s[i].sortt()
s[i].print()

for objects of vector